# How do you move left during Night 5 on mobile?

Tags: fnaf-sister-location

I got Sister Location on my phone a long with a few other FNAF games on my iPhone but I've been having some trouble on Night 5. Circus Baby tells you to go left but there doesn't seem to be any way to go left.

I looked it up and apparently you're suppose to hold the top left of the screen to go left but that hasn't been working. The very top left is how you crawl faster but that ends up getting you killed after a second or two and pressing just to the right of the crawl faster button doesn't do anything either. I also tried to go over to the secret room but still got killed almost immediately.

The only video I could find just seemed to be the person holding down the crawl button while looking around which also didn't work.

How do you go left or right on mobile in Sister Location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little while of messing around I figured out how. You need to repeatedly swipe left while crawling to move to the left. The same goes for when you want to go to the right, just repeatedly swipe to the right.